# is there a difference in performance between these two fan designs

Tags: airflow, aerodynamics, fan

These two fans are usually used in hairdryer is there a difference between them in performance if both have same rpm and same outer diameter.
[image]

Comment: Depends on the housing designs.

Comment: They are different types. One is a centrifugal and the other is axial. They may be designed to run at different speeds and power levels.

Comment: but centrifugal fan usually pushes air side ways this one has airflow backwards acting like the axial on the right @Transistor

Comment: "*... this one has airflow backwards ...*" Link to the datasheet or a datasheet for a similar product that says it can be run backwards. Maybe it can.

Comment: @Abdulwali I think you mean one changes the axis of flow and the other does not.

Comment: They will have completely different performance curves with regards to input torque, rpms, pressure and flow.